# unable to forward form created in notes designer 9 to notes 9 to share with clients

Tags: lotus-notes

I have create a form in Notes Designer version 9.0 and i am unable to forward this form to any users, as i do not find Forward Button under Create Menu.

Not sure if am looking at right options to forward the form, please help.

Thank You
Venu

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "forward the form". That's not something a Notes developer would normally say, so it's difficult to understand what you really mean. In Notes, forms are used to create documents, but we do not forward forms. We forward the documents that were created using the form.

Comment: @Richard Schwartz: Hi, am new to notes designer, I am trying to create a form for a survey. And i managed to create a form with the required information. Now i am not sure how to use the form to publish to end user's and get the survey completed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two classic approaches to publishing a form for users to fill out.

1. Set the Store Form in Document property on the form (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_STORING_FORMS_OVER.html)), and add mail fields (SendTo, Subject, etc.) to it. Add a button that is only visible to you and use @MailSend code in that button to send a document to the people you want to fill out the form. Add another button that is visible to the recipients, and use @MailSend code in that button to send the document back to you, or to a mail-in database. The form will accompany the document wherever it goes. (It will be stored in a field called $Form.)
2. Just put the form in a database on your server, and set the ACL so that your users can create documents in that database. Send an email message to all the users containing a button with code that executes @Command([Compose]...) with the options set to point to the correct server, database, and form.

Note that both of the above techniques assume that the people you want to fill out the form have Notes clients. If that's not the case, then what you'll want to do is this:

3. Just put the form in a database on a server that is running the Domino http task, and set the ACL so that your users can create documents in that database. Send an email message to all the users containing a link in the form http://server/path/databasename.nsf/formname?OpenForm

Comment: Thank you for providing inputs in creating a Survey Form. I finally created a Survey form and got it forwarded to my mail box, which can now be shared with end user's.

Comment: However i have another question, just in case if possible.  Currently Radio buttons in the form can be used only in edit mode, unlike the "Button" options, which can used just in read mode (eg: if i send a mail with "Button" end users can just click the button in read mode and i would get the reply). Anyway possible the same method can be used  for Radio button in form ?

Comment: Field values can't be changed in read mode, but you can design your form so that it automatically opens in edit mode. You can do this either by adding a postOpen script that sets source.editmode = true, or you can simply go to the Form Properties dialog, click on the second tab (the one with the propeller hat icon) and clcik the checkbox for the "Automatically enable enable Edit Mode" property,